# What should I do in my notice period besides finishing my current project?

Tags: termination

Some of you might remember the question I asked a month ago, [My performance heavily suffers from distractions and partial code rewrites. How can I fix this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35083/my-performance-heavily-suffers-from-distractions-and-partial-code-rewrites-how). As I expected, the week after, I had a meeting with HR and they gave me my termination notice, citing a lack of return on the substantial investment they made in me. my 6 weeks notice started on november 2nd, so I'm currently in the second of my 6 weeks.

My boss told me I have to finish my current project, which should be nearly done, after which I may stay home for the rest of my notice period while still receiving full pay. He also told me that if the project is finished before the end of the period, I may put him on my resumé as a reference. I also get 1 day off per week to take care of job applications and interviews.

I want to ensure that my exit does not jeopardize the company. I will definitely finish the project and discuss what I made so far with my coworker, but besides that, I'm not quite sure what else I should do.

What are the recommended actions to take during a notice period?

Comment: Also, I am quite surprised that I didn't find a question yet that discusses this. I looked through all the questions with the termination tag, but most of those deal with slightly different aspects, like how to prevent it or how to handle it on your resumé or subsequent interviews. Or is this just to broad to discuss?

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic explicitly mentions "Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)" as a possible topic. Also, The intent of this question is to be generally useful. I have updated the question to be of a more general nature so other people can also use it.

Comment: Apart from finishing ongoing work and transferring your knowledge to your successor(s), normally there is hardly anything to do during your notice period. Apparently your boss doesn't want anything else either; but to be sure, you may ask him when you're nearly done with everything you can think of.

Comment: That's very reasonable terms in your notice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the recommended actions to take during a notice period?

Apparently, you should finish your current project, then stay home.

You should strive to finish "before the end of the period", as a decent recommendation from your boss might come in handy.

You should ask your boss if there is any knowledge transfer you could provide that will benefit the department. And you should ask if there is documentation that you could write which could be helpful.

And if for some reason you haven't already started your job search, you should jump into that full bore. Finding your next job (and in particular, one that fits your personal needs) is now your #1 priority above all else.

As I suggested before, you should seek out support groups who could help you in finding suitable employment, despite your condition.

Comment: The support group through which I got my current employment are open to helping me again. They need a reference from the unemployment bureau, which I cannot get before the end of my notice period. And adjoining to my notice period, I already have holiday plans with my parents which have been planned for months now, so in effect, I cannot get in that support group until next year.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. "I want to ensure that my exit does not jeopardize the company."

The question is "in what way could your exit jeopardize your company?" I doubt that they'd let you work on anything that's critical to the existence of the company and if you can't work on it, you can't screw it up. Moreover, they seem to have a pretty good grip on what you are doing and not doing for them. Non-performance attracts supervisory attention. Don't worry about them, they covered themselves pretty well. Worry about you.

> 2. "I will definitely finish the project and discuss what I made so far with my coworker."

You may be taking an outcome for granted when you shouldn't, given what you let us know from your previous post on how you performed your job. Finishing your project is your #1 priority, which eclipses all other priorities. If you don't finish, you not only not get the remaining time of your notice off with pay, you won't get the reference from your manager either. And not getting your reference from your manager has definite implications on how more difficult for you to get another job. In general, they are being much nicer with you than I would have been so do take heed when they say they give you a chance to finish. You have only four weeks to go and time has a way of flying. Fast.

> 3. "What are the recommended actions to take during a notice period?"

There are actions you could take such as updating your resume and sending out requests for an interview but I don't recommend them for you at this stage. You need to finish your project and you can't afford to do anything that either detracts, distracts or off-tracks you from finishing your project. And finishing your project may very well require that you at least partially attack, address and resolve the lack of discipline that caused you to lose your job in the first place - That's not a small order of business. You can't afford to screw this up, either by omission or by commission. All other actions of yours have to wait until you have completed your project to your management's satisfaction.

Once you're finished with your project, you need to take a hard, painfully honest look as to what is it about your performance that got you canned, and what you can or are willing to do about it. But even that part, critical as it may be to your prospects of future employment, will have to wait until you have finished your project to your management's satisfaction.